# Ignore empty lists in jaguar serializer in Flitter

Tags: json, dart, flutter, serialization

Currently there is a way to ignore json keys that have null values from Jaguar Serializer https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_serializer. However, I could not find a way to ignore empty lists. Is there a way to do so? I tried setting the list to null but it still serializes as an empty list in json

Answer (score -1):

Currently no.

I am the author of Jaguar Serializer. Please add an issue here: https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_serializer/issues

I will fix it.